# How to show error if a text box in form is sent empty?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What I'm trying to say is that I am trying to make a login and sign up page with the help of mysql and php. I have created a table with : "Create table Harry (username varchar(50) primary key not null, password varchar(50) not null)";
But the thing is when I open the sign up page and fill nothing in the form i.e. Username textbox and password textbox, it sends an empty string value in  the table and then one can login without even entering any data and by just clicking on the logIn button. What I want is that they sxhould recieve an error message of the form being empty? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add this php snippet after your input

```
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control login-form-control" required = "true"><?php echo $_GET['m1'];?>
```

this wil show error when the page loads so you need to add

```
  error_reporting(0);
```

at the start of your same form page

the page where the data goes. check for the input "email"

```
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if (!($email))
    {
        $m = "<span style='color: red;'>Not a valid Email Id</span>";
        header('location: formPage.php?m1='.$m);
    }
```

Here the location I filled is `formPage.php` which you will rename to your form page.

Comment: what is 'm1' in $_GET['m1'] and why are there two dollars ($) in the if statement?

Comment: m1 is the message you are extracting from your page url

Comment: sorry there shold be only one $ sign

Comment: See, by GET method you can extract properties set after the ? sign

Comment: Thanks. i'll try it and tell ya.